# Controls in a UIScrollView won't work below screen height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have UIButtons/UISliders around 900 pixels down a UIView which is on a UIScrollView. I am alloc/init the scrollView and the UIView frame at 0,0,375,950 and setting the scrollView.contentSize to the same and have enabled userInteraction. Yet I am unable to interact with any controls below the size of the screen(outside of 675 y).

```
self.viewInsideScrollView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 950)];
self.viewInsideScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.viewInsideScrollView.frame.size.width, self.viewInsideScrollView.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 950)];
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES;
self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.viewInsideScrollView];
```

The buttons, sliders and a colletionView were all added and constrained to the UIView on top of the scrollView via Storyboards

Comment: Check for the size of the view on which you place your controls.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: One thing that sticks out is that your scroll view should most likely have the same frame as your device. If your screen has a height of 675 points you should instantiate your scroll view to that size `self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 675)];` Having a scroll view taller than the screen does not make a lot of sense as the scroll view will not scroll as much as necessary to show all content. This may not be the cause of the problem however.